# Ruby: condition in multiple lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In other programming languages, I can separate into lines the conditions by breaking it down in the logical operator, but in ruby (I'm using rails) it seems that not. Is a thing of the code or about the syntax?:

```
<% if (current_user && current_user.id == @user.id)
   || @user.profile_privacy === 0 
   || (@user.profile_privacy === 1 
      && current_user 
      && current_user.user_friendships.find_by_friend_id(@user.id)
      && current_user.user_friendships.find_by_friend_id(@user.id).state == true ) %>
```

Comment: You should try and move this logic out of the template and into your controller.

Comment: I don´t know how, I think it'd be quite complicated because It's about different html returned in different cases. Anyway, know how can I fix this? @Sam

Comment: I'm just writing you an example, give me a few minutes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have all that logic in your view, but to fix your code move the operators to the end of the lines:

```
<% if (current_user && current_user.id == @user.id) || 
  @user.profile_privacy === 0 || 
  (@user.profile_privacy === 1 && 
  current_user && 
  current_user.user_friendships.find_by_friend_id(@user.id) &&  
  current_user.user_friendships.find_by_friend_id(@user.id).state == true ) 
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try and keep as much logic out of your template as possible.

For example, you could move some of the logic into your `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def has_user_as_friend user
    user_friendships.find_by_friend_id(user).state == true
  end

  def is_private
    profile_privacy === 0
  end
end
```

And you could move some of it into your controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @is_current_user = current_user.id == @user.id
end
```

Then, your condition may become a little simpler:

```
<% if (@is_current_user || @user.is_private) %>
```

I haven't replicated your conditions exactly, but hopefully this gives you a couple of ideas as to how you could simplify your `if` statement.

Comment: Sorry - I know this isn't an exact answer, infused has it right above. But, I thought it was worth mentioning!